# How can I find out which procedures a particular turtle (Netlogo) is calling at every tick?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to debug the movements of three particular turtles. All but three turtles, out of the set number of turtles (150) are moving as expected. Three of them however behave, irrationally, going through walls (which they are not programmed to do) or stopping to move for few ticks near the walls and then starting to move again. 
I understand that there is no debugging in Netlogo and that one needs to get creative. I am using inspect and print, to get an idea what those three particular turtles are doing (or are about to do) at every tick.

```
ask turtles [ if [who] of self = 124 [ inspect self] ]   
ask turtle 124 [ print heading]
```

What would really help, is after this to add command to tell/report which procedures and in which order the specific turtle is calling at every tick. I have been looking at forums but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a print statement at the beginning of all the relevant procedures along the lines of `type self print "I am at procedure-name"`. The  self identifies which turtle is doing the procedure. Note that this assumes you are already in the turtle context so `self` makes sense.

As an aside, instead of `ask turtles [ if [who] of self = 124 [ inspect self]` you can simply say `inspect turtle 124`

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. Will give that a shot. But I am not sure I understand what you mean by '...you are already in the turtle context..'  I should be able to see the print statements in the command center, no?  (forgive my ignorance, I am new to this and to the mindset necessary for understanding this programming language)

Comment: You can put print statements in the command center but that won't solve your problem because that won't have each turtle do the print as it reaches that step in the procedure. Turtle context means a procedure that is run by turtles.